# How to read file as vector<vector<double>>?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I have data like this

```
4.0 0.8
4.1 0.7
4.4 1.1
3.9 1.2
4.0 1.0
```

I have written my program

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
vector<double> v;
ifstream in("primer.dat");
double word;
while(in >> word)
v.push_back(word);
for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
cout << v[i] << endl;
}
```

But now I have realized that for further calculations in my code,I need data as (`vector <vector> double)`.I would prefer not to reshape the vector.Is it possible to read data as vector of vectors?

Comment: What do you mean saying "not to reshape the vector"?

Comment: For starters do you need a vector<vector<double>> or a vector<double> cause you actually say both. Also what do you mean by reshape the vector... To me it looks like you just read from your file and then split each line with the ' ' character to create your vector...

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I can read it as vector,that could use reinterpret cast,but that would make things complicated.

Comment: @LBesancon Yes,I need vector<vector<double>>.

Comment: @RichardRublev not sure I understand what you meant but check my answer it might help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> v;
    std::ifstream in( "primer.dat" );
    std::string record;

    while ( std::getline( in, record ) )
    {
        std::istringstream is( record );
        std::vector<double> row( ( std::istream_iterator<double>( is ) ),
                                 std::istream_iterator<double>() );
        v.push_back( row );
    }

    for ( const auto &row : v )
    {
        for ( double x : row ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }        
}
```

Comment: @Garg Ankit Thanks.:)

Comment: An other nice way of doing it, definitely deserves the upvote :)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if I fully understand what you meant but if I did this code should work just fine then:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string& str, char sep)
    {
        std::vector<std::string> result;
        std::istringstream iss(str);
        std::string sub;
        while (std::getline(iss, sub, sep))
            result.push_back(sub);
        return result;
    }

int main() {
    vector<vector<double> >  completeVector ;
    ifstream in("primer.dat");
    string word;
    while(in >> word){
        std::vector<std::string> splitS = split(word, ' ');
        std::vector<double> line ;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < splitS.size() ; i++){
            line.push_back(stod(splitS[i]));
        }
        completeVector.push_back(line);
    }

// For printing out the result
    for(int i = 0 ; i < completeVector.size() ; i++){
        std::vector<double> tmp = completeVector[i];
        for(int j = 0 ; j < tmp.size() ; j++){
            std::cout << tmp[j] << std::endl ;
        }
     }  
}
```

It compiles for sure and it should have the behaviour that you're looking for.
If it doesn't let me know in the comments.

Comment: Instead of implementing your own `split()`, `strtok()` can be used: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

Comment: Totally true but I just have my own functions define in a file and it was just as easy pasting it here as it was to use strtok() but you are completely right.

Comment: It is always good to use library methods, as it will make the solution less prone to bugs.

Comment: Sure I don't deny that at all as I've said before you are right about that. OP can use whatever he wants, both solutions work anyway and the question was not really on the split() part. It was just more convenient for me to use this split function as it directly uses a std::string and returns a std::string instead of a char*.

Comment: @GargAnkit Bad advice. Also splitting isn't needed at all, `while(in >> word){` already strips all whitespaces.

Comment: Well the split is used in case of a csv file which is more common for this kind of problem

Comment: @LBesancon I have compiled it with any problems,just how to print Complet vector on screen?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  vector<vector<double>> v;
  ifstream in("primer.dat");
  string line;
  while(std::getline(in, line))
  {
    v.push_back(vector<double>());
    stringstream ss(line);
    double word;
    while(ss >> word)
    {
      v.back().push_back(word);
    }
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
  {
    for(int j = 0; j < v[i].size(); j++)
    {
      cout << v[i][j] << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
  }

}
```